# rosnode getting params from the parameter server

Tags: rosnode, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to tell during runtime, which nodes are using which params from the parameter server? (just like it's possible to tell which nodes are listening to topics using the rostopic info command) Also, are params 'latched' to a node. Is it possible to change the param value and have the node get the new value?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236207/rosnode-getting-params-from-the-parameter-server/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way to determine which nodes are using a parameter.

The common way to change parameters in a node at run-time is to use [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).

roscpp also provides [cached parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Cached_Parameters), which can be used to keep a few local parameters up to date with the master, but this increases the load on the ROS master.

If you have data that needs to be explicitly passed between two nodes on a regular basis, it is better to use a topic because it is easier to inspect and record.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0